# How to parser compressed pdf in FPDI and FPDF?

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, fpdf, fpdi

I am using FPDF and FPDI to make PDF with a pre-uploaded PDF template.
In Laravel.

I get the below error when I `setSourceFile` for to make a new pdf.

**ERROR**

**This PDF document probably uses a compression technique that is not supported FPDI.**

```
$pdf = new \setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi();          
$pdf->addPage();
$pdf->setSourceFile('My-Template-PDF.pdf');
```

Is there any technique that allows this pdf to be parsed?

or Is there any other way or workaround to parse compressed PDF?

Comment: "_is not supported by the free parser_" sounds like there would be a paid parser that might be able to de-compress. Did you check FPDI's page?

Comment: I have the Paid version also but that also not parsing some pdf, i have check on https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi-pdf-parser/details

Comment: @brombeer  can you suggest any other options to parse the pdf as a template in PHP?
I have checked dom-pdf also but they did not allow a template parse.

Comment: @always-a-learner if you have the paid version this error message will never be thrown. If you have other errors they mostly might be thrown because the PDF is simply faulty.

Comment: @JanSlabon yes sir i get what you pointing out, but is there any technique to parse the compressed PDF to use it as a base template in any other library?

Comment: @always-a-learner you wrote that you "have the Paid version also". Install it correctly and the error message will be gone.